# Managing common code components with TFS

Tags: .net, build, tfs

I'm setting up a [Team Foundation Service](https://tfspreview.com/) for me and a friend. We'll be using it to create a few hobby projects.

I've set it up with a single Team Project, and the source control is currently structured as so

$\Projects\CommonLib

$\Projects\Project1

$\Projects\Project2

Where Project1 is a game, Project2 is a win8 app and commonlib is our common, reusable code which will be referenced by both Projec1 and Project2. Each project will consist of a solution containing multiple projects.

CommonLib needs to be distributed to the two projects. My initial idea was to check the CommonLib binaries into a source control folder and branch it out to the two other projects, deploying it using some sort of custom Team Build process.

There's a problem, though. It's rather tedious to work like this, especially now in the early stages of development. We want to be able to add code to CommonLib at a rapid basis and whilst the process described above is fine when the codebase has matured and won't be modified frequently, it will be a hastle to perform all those steps every time something is added there (build -> deploy -> merge).

On the other end of the scale, we could create a development solution for e.g. Project1 which also contains the CommonLib projects. However, this means that we might cause problems for Project2 if we cause breaking changes by mistake. This can be managed better with the branch+merge strategy described above

So my question is, am I missing any options which might enable us to retain the control whilst still being able to keep the development process' complexity at a minimum? I'm sure this is a common problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it help if you didn't merge the binaries over into the product's space?

```
$\Projects\CommonLib\1.0\Source
$\Projects\CommonLib\1.0\Bin
$\Projects\CommonLib\Dev\Source
$\Projects\CommonLib\Dev\Bin

$\Projects\Project1

$\Projects\Project2
```

Have a build set up for common, have it check the binaries into the Bin folder and then just have Project1 and Project2 reference them over in common. As you can see, I also put in a 1.0 Branch of Dev in Common, so that when Project1 or Project2 gewt ready to release they could branch common dev into a versioned folder and cut themselves off from the other projects changes to common.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you can't have both projects in the same build solution, even though each developer is only interested in one of the projects?

With both projects in one solution, and the common project in the same solution, then whenever either of you make changes to the common module you will immediately know if you have broken something in either of the dependent projects because everything is built together.  You can then update the dependent code that is broken by your change to the common module, or coordinate with the project owner to get that code updated.  As the projects mature, you should expect to see fewer changes to the common modules.

Do not check in your breaking changes until everything builds clean and the unit tests pass. If you make a breaking change to a common module, you are responsible for fixing all the dependent code. This builds character, and new appreciation for the skill of making core changes without breaking the published interface or semantic. ;>

Obviously, this "include everything" approach doesn't scale with large dev teams and large numbers of projects. But when you're operating with a larger team, you should switch to an automated build / shared build server workflow where dependent projects decide which build of intermediates they are dependent upon and can decide when to "roll up" to newer releases of modules they depend upon - independent of the release cycles of the dependent modules.  For two devs and two projects with common code, you don't need this level of dependency management.